# recv() returns strange buffer C++

Tags: c++, network-programming, winsock, winsock2, winsockets

I know C++ for quite long, but started using it for my purposes some what a year and a half ago.
I started learning network programming on C++ and the first networking project is "File Transfering between hosts over TCP/IP" which sounds kind easy but I am stuck with sending data.

I am trying to send small buffer less than 4KB, so buffer[4096] works fine for me, but I am planning to expand this. WSAStartup(), socket(), bind(), listen(), accept() functions work fine and values for them are initialised for both Server and Client, but I am dealing with other problems, maybe recv(), send() etc.
I still couldn't find the source of the problem.

Also it would be a ton helpful if somebody give me an example of transfering files over TCP/IP, but not in one packet, I want the file to be chunked and sent in parts or as it's called "ring model", but I couldn't find a working model;

P.S. This is first time I am asking here, pls give feedback about how well all of this is written, so that I could write more informative for community help, thanks)

Server

```
char* buffer = new char[4096];
ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
ofstream file("a.txt", ios::binary);
int err = recv(conn, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
file << buffer;
file.close();
if (err == 0)
{
    printf("Client diconnected...\n");
}

printf("Quitting...\n");
delete[] buffer;
```

Client

```
ifstream file("a.txt", ios::binary);
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
int size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
char* buffer = new char[size];
file.read(buffer, size);
file.close();

int err = send(client, buffer, size, 0);
if (err == 0)
{
    printf("Disconnecting...\n");
}

printf("Quitting...\n");
delete[] buffer;
```

"a.txt" file on Client side is 45 bytes in here are 45 * 'a'

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

And this is what I get on Server side, file size is 14 bytes

```
aaaaaaaa ’pÈ/
```

Comment: You may find [Boost Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to be highly relevant for your use case.

Comment: You also want to pay attention to the fact that recv(sock, buffer, 4096, 0) doesn't receive 4096 bytes.

Comment: You got the answer below. (sizeof problems). You also asked for feedback on your code. It's C++ but as it used to be written literally 25 years ago. C++ has moved on a lot. Since you learned it a long time ago you might be interested in buying a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that covers the newer aspects of C++. It's a far superior lanugage than it used to be (and this is coming from someone who always resists any change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the pointer type.

You may want to read up on more modern (as in after 1998) C++. We have `std::vector` nowadays, and that has a convenient `size` method. It would return `4096` for your buffer. Also, vector handles `new[]` and `delete[]` for you.

The fact that you get 8 "a"'s suggests that you built for x64. The remaining bytes are garbage; you should check how many bytes `recv` actually wrote to `buffer`. You cannot assume that you got all the bytes you asked for (whether that's 8 or 4096).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that sizeof(buffer) in this line -->

int err = recv(conn, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

will return sizeof(char*) which is 4 bytes in a 32 bit program or 8 bytes in a 64 bits program instead of 4096 because it is not a static array as in you did not declare it as char buffer[4096]. So, either declare it as char buffer[4096] or convert the above code to

int err = recv(conn, buffer, 4096, 0);

Answer (score 1):

Two additional points:

- TCP is a streaming protocol (not "message based"), so there's no guarantee that a single `recv()` will get everything sent in a single `send()`.
- The server line `file << buffer;` assumes `buffer` is zero terminated.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN state that :

> If no error occurs, **recv returns the number of bytes received** and the
> buffer pointed to by the buf parameter will contain this data
> received. If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return
> value is zero.
>
> Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error
> code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv

test if you actually read 45 bytes and check if there's an error (WSAGetLastError function)